# 500 error with deploying NextJS App with GraphQL Queries

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, graphql

I created a single page app with NextJS14 using GraphQL queries through Hygraph. My app runs fine locally but does not work when deployed. When I deploy on Vercel, I get 500 errors for my queries and mutations. When I deploy on Netlify, I get 404 errors for my queries and mutations. I set up the app to have a form. When the form submits, it prevents the default behavior and calls a function in my app/components/Results.tsx file. That file has the async functions that are using server components to return either the data requested or a success message. The repo for this is public at https://github.com/ryanjames1729/crud-with-forms. The Vercel build is at https://crud-with-forms.vercel.app/ and the Netlify build is at https://crud-with-forms.netlify.app/.

I have 4 forms that call the functions depending on what is being requested. Here is an example of my create mutation that calls the async function on Results.tsx

```
// app/page.tsx
{ create && (
          <form className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center" onSubmit={ (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            console.log(createName, createScore)
            const names = postName(createName, createScore) 
            names.then((data: any) => {
              console.log(data)
              setPostUpdate('Your post has been sent!');
              setCreateName('');
              setCreateScore('');
          })
        }
          }>
```

Here is the async function that gets called:

```
// app/components/Results.tsx
export async function postName(name: string, points: string) {
  const endpoint = process.env.GRAPHQL_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT;
  const token = process.env.GRAPHQL_TOKEN;

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint || "", {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  });
 
  const { createUsername }: any = await graphQLClient.request(`
  mutation CreateUsername($name: String!, $points: String!) {
    createUsername(data: {name: $name, points: $points}) {
      id
      name
      points
    }
  }
  `, { name, points }); // variables must be part of the request arguments!
  const id = createUsername.id;
  console.log("id: ", id);
  const { pubishUsername }: any = await graphQLClient.request(`
    mutation PublishUsername($id: ID!) {
        publishUsername(where: {id: $id}) {
        id
        name
        points
        }
    }
    `, { id }); // variables must be part of the request arguments!
  console.log(createUsername);
  return createUsername;
}
```

I know this is an issue on my end. Vercel is indicating that I'm called a POST request on "/" which is calling a dynamic URL instead of an absolute URL. I just don't know how to prevent that behavior so that the build is successful.

I have tried moving the async function to different places in the app directory but it cannot be on the page.tsx because that page uses client and async functions in Next now require to be using client.